# Switching from UK tourist visa to fiancé visa

Tags: visas, uk, weddings

I currently hold a UK short term tourist visa. Recently we have decided to marry with my partner (who lives in UK), who I've been together with for 5 years. For us to register the marriage in UK I need a Marriage Visitor visa, also known as fiancé visa. My tourist visa expires in March, but we'd like to get married earlier, in January.

Is it possible to switch from tourist visa to the fiancé one before the tourist one expires?

Comment: Note: a "marriage visitor visa" is for people who intend to marry in the UK but leave again afterwards. If you intend to marry a brit and then live in the UK you are looking for a "family visa". Afaict there is no visa officially called a "fiance visa".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coming back with the answer. Got my visa, everything is fine. Totally ok to go from the general tourist visa to the fiancée visa before the tourist one expires.